# Edit a formatted moment object

Tags: javascript, momentjs

If I create a formatted moment, I cannot modify it (e.g. add days).

For example, after the following code, finish represents a moment at 2015-10-23:

```
start = moment("2015-10-23");
finish = start.clone().add(7, 'd');
```

Whereas if I just use the start of the current day, as follows, it will update the moment:

```
start = moment().startOf('day');
finish = start.clone().add(7, 'd');
```

How do I edit the date of a formatted moment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should work fine. You can edit the date of a formatted moment using

```
start = moment("2015-10-23");
finish = start.clone().add(7, 'd');
console.log(finish.toDate());
```

use `.toDate()` to verify the same. I think you are getting confused by looking at the value of `_i` in the moment object. You need not worry about this as `_i` is the input used when creating the moment object. It can be a string, a number, an array, or a Date object.